# Meaning of warning "Class implementation may not have super class"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a very basic Objective-C class.

MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"
@interface MyClass()
@end

@implementation MyClass: NSObject  {
    NSMutableArray* _myArray;
}
@end
```

Xcode is showing the following warning on the `@implementation` line:

> Class implementation may not have super class

The warning goes away if I remove the `NSMutableArray* _myArray;` line.

**What does this warning mean? What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete `NSObject` in the `implementation` part. The super class has to be specified only in the `interface`.

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSMutableArray* _myArray;
}
@end
```

Comment: I just don't get why the warning disappeared when I removed the private variable declaration...

Comment: I guess because there is nothing to implement

Answer (score 2):

```
@implementation MyClass: NSObject
```

You're not supposed to inherit from NSObject in the implementation.
you already got it in the `@interface MyClass: NSObject`